# Specification of vararg inside type declaration

Tags: java, generics, java-8

In attempt to utilize only predefined functional interfaces from `java.util.function` I've started to wonder why it's not possible to specify varargs inside type declaration. For example I want to provide API which can be used like this

```
object.method((x, y, z) -> x + y - z)
```

Where `method` takes mathematical function of n arguments. Here is what I want my `object` interface to look like

```
interface I {
    I method(ToDoubleFunction<double...> f);
}
```

I do realize that I can define my own funcional interface, or change API slightly specifying `double[]` inside angle brackets. I'm curious only why mentioned above way of doing it is not feasible.

**Edit:**

In the comments there is an explanation why example above is not correct usage of varargs. Radiodef divided my quesion into two separated ones

> 1. why vararg is not allowed as a generic argument and
> 2. why you cannot declare and access vararg by name in Java.

Due to the title of the question I have to stick with the first one. Here is expected behavior:

```
 ToDoubleFunction<double...> lambda = (double... d) -> d[0] + d[1] - d[2];
 lambda.applyAsDouble(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Can you give a useful example for what `method` would do in this scenario, where not knowing the arity of the function would still lead to a useful operation?

Comment: Java varargs don't work this way `(x, y, z) -> x + y - z`. The arguments are passed as an array so what you are wanting to do is access array indexes by name and a vararg can take an array with any number of indexes.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that I don't think what you're really looking for is variable arity, but rather implicit support for n-tuples.  Tuples are much more useful because the arity is still built into the type.  Unfortunately, Java does not support tuples.

Comment: @MarkPeters Problem domain behind this question is function optimization. Scenario is that I use builder pattern with many chained method which take functions(predicates) and build method which takes starting vector(tuple) where arity is implicitly specified.

Comment: @Radiodef I see, totally misused the thing. A whole layer of folding(mapping/substituting) argument list should be added to lambdas for this to work. The syntax is nice though.

Comment: @Radiodef And yet this does not answer the question. Yes my lambda is uncorrect but after fixing it I'd still have been able to write `f.applyAsDouble(x, y, z) if such syntax had been legal.

Comment: A vararg lambda would be `(double... d) -> d[0] + d[1] - d[2]` because that is how varargs work in Java. That is actually valid syntax. You are really asking 2 questions: *1. why vararg is not allowed as a generic argument* and *2. why you cannot declare and access vararg by name in Java*. Note that I also did not post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring a method parameter as varargs implies that the *caller* may provide an arbitrary number of arguments which the receiver will process like an array.

So it makes no difference for the implementation whether you write:

```
static double f(double... a) { return a[0]+a[1]-a[2]; }
```

or

```
static double f(double[]  a) { return a[0]+a[1]-a[2]; }
```

So for writing down a lambda expression, which *implements* a function, it is irrelevant whether a parameter is specified as varargs, especially as you can omit the parameter types so nobody sees whether `[]` or `...` is implied.

So when you refuse to use your own interface, you will have to write down

```
ToDoubleFunction<double[]> f=a->a[0]+a[1]-a[2];
```

and, of course, keep in mind that your code assumes a certain array length.

With a helper interface, things could be easier:

```
interface F3 extends ToDoubleFunction<double[]> {
    double apply(double a0, double a1, double a2);
    default double applyAsDouble(double[] a) {
        return apply(a[0], a[1], a[2]);
    }
}
```

then you could write:

```
ToDoubleFunction<double[]> f=(F3)(x,y,z)->x+y-z;
```

Similar things would work with an equivalent `F4` interface, etc., and you could process them all as `ToDoubleFunction<double[]>` but the compiler won’t warn you when you mix code with different assumption about the array length (just the same problem as with varargs when you assume a not-so variable arity).

Calling an array expecting method which doesn’t declare the parameter as vararg can always be wrapped with a helper method that *does* expect varargs:

```
static double apply(ToDoubleFunction<double[]> f, double... arg) {
    return f.applyAsDouble(arg);
}
```

with such a method you can evaluate your function as simple as `apply(f, 1, 2, 3)`

Did I mention that the compiler won’t warn you when the number of parameters don’t match?